# Which ebook readers can play videos?

Tags: ebook-readers

I am looking for help to determine which ebook readers that are currently on the market can play videos. Specifically I would like to know if there is a model that works well with online learning pages like Udemy or O'Reilly learning.

Many of the ebook reader specifications mention that there may be a browser on the device but there is no mention of whether these browsers support videos. Both Udemy and O'Reilly have apps. It would be an acceptable solution if the ereader fully supports Android apps that play videos.

I am aware that a tablet could solve the issue but am interested in ereaders. Many thanks for your advice.